# @Scheduled not working : Spring 4

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduler

Can't get @Scheduled working.

What i have :

1. `@EnableScheduling` on my configuration class.
2. scheduler bean is under component scan
3. `@Scheduled` applied on a method :

   ```
   @Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
   public void callOutLogsPurgeScheduler3(){
       try{
           LOG.info("executing some job for something...");
           ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata");
           long _30DaysBack = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(30).atZone(zone).toEpochSecond();
           //doing something here
       }catch(Exception e){
           LOG.info("Error while executing some job for something :  {}",e);
       }
   }
   ```

Neither of the two logs is getting printed in my logs.
Tried breakpoints, never getting triggered.

Can someone point me if i might be missing something here?
What could possibly be wrong?

I am running on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: If it isn't working then `@EnableScheduling` and your component with `@Scheduled` aren't in the same application context.t

Comment: Getting the same issue. I am using `@Scheduled(fixedDelay=20*1000, initialDelay = 1000)`. How did you fix it finally?

Comment: What Spring version? I found that @Scheduled annotation processor (ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor) seems to be broken in Spring 4.1.9. It detects annotated methods, but don't launch the tasks. A workaround is to trigger onApplicationEvent method on it, that launch the tasks correctly: applicationContext.getBean(ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.class).onApplicationEvent(new ContextRefreshedEvent(applicationContext)). It's corrected from Spring 4.2+